# How to call click event in Typescript appended html button?

Tags: angular, angular8, syncfusion

I've a button which is created in appended html in typescript.I added a click function which name is btnCancelNewClientAppointment but it doesn't call it's function. How can i do that?

```
 let dialogObj: Dialog = (document.querySelector('.e-schedule-dialog') as EJ2Instance).ej2_instances[0] as Dialog;

  dialogObj.footerTemplate ='<div>' +  
  '<button id="saveButton" #saveSavedClientButton class="e-control e-btn e-primary sendButton" data-ripple="true">Kaydet</button>' +
  '<button id="cancelButton" #btnCancelNewClientAppointment class="e-control e-btn" data-ripple="true" (click)="btnCancelNewClientAppointment()">İptal</button>'+  
  '</div>' 


 btnCancelNewClientAppointment():void{
    let dialogObj: Dialog = (document.querySelector('.e-schedule-dialog') as EJ2Instance).ej2_instances[0] as Dialog;
    dialogObj.hide();
  }
```

Comment: Angular will not recognize components added via strings or similar. Dynamic components need to be handled in a special way: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: Usually if you're having to create components dynamically like this, you're not following the proper Angular pattern. Your HTML template should be in your Angular's HTML. You can make it appear and disappear using something like `ngIf`.

Answer (score 0):

We have checked your reported issue, we suspect that the cause of the issue is to check the click function properly, you might give the function name and some variable name same. So, change the function name. Please find the below code snippet:

Kaydet +

```
<button id="cancelButton" #btnCancelNewClientApp class="e-control e-btn" data-ripple="true" (click)="btnCancelNewClientAppointment()">İptal</button>
```

Please find the below link for the reported issue:
https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly/issues/661

For your convenience, we have prepared a sample. Please find the below sample link
Sample link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8cqlw?file=app.component.html

Could you please check the above sample and get back to us if you need further assistance with this?

Regards,

Saranya D